Error in the test case due to memory violation or it took too long
Im doing a program and the results are right, but to one case test it doesn't work, i don't know exactly why.
The reason is due to memory violation or because it took too long to output a result.
My program is about Machine Learning, i need to see based on behaviors if a student is approved or not, using the distance between points.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // To use malloc
#define MAX_SAMPLES 300000
#define MAX_STUDENTS 300000

typedef struct {
    float study_hours;
    float average_grade;
    int pass_or_fail;
    float distance;
} samples;

typedef struct {
    float study_hours;
    float average_grade;
} evaluated;

// Function to adjust the maximum heap
void heapify(samples sample_array[], int n, int i) {
    int largest = i; // Initialize the largest as root
    int left = 2 * i + 1; // index of the left child
    int right = 2 * i + 2; // index of the right child

    // If the left child is larger than root
    if (left < n && sample_array[left].distance > sample_array[largest].distance)
        largest = left;

    // If the right child is larger than largest so far
    if (right < n && sample_array[right].distance > sample_array[largest].distance)
        largest = right;

    // If largest is not root
    if (largest != i) {
        // Swap the largest with root
        samples temp = sample_array[i];
        sample_array[i] = sample_array[largest];
        sample_array[largest] = temp;

        // Recursively adjust the affected heap
        heapify(sample_array, n, largest);
    }
}

// Main function of the Heap Sort
void heapSort(samples sample_array[], int n) {
    // Build max heap
    for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        heapify(sample_array, n, i);

    // Extract elements from heap one by one
    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        // Move current root to end
        samples temp = sample_array[0];
        sample_array[0] = sample_array[i];
        sample_array[i] = temp;

        // call max heapify on the reduced heap
        heapify(sample_array, i, 0);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n_samples;
    int n_students_to_be_evaluated;
    int k;
    int pass_count;
    int fail_count;

    scanf("%d %d %d", &n_samples, &n_students_to_be_evaluated, &k);

   samples sample_array[MAX_SAMPLES];
   evaluated evaluated_array[MAX_STUDENTS];

    // Reading the samples
    for (int j = 0; j < n_samples; j++) {
        scanf("%f %f %d", &sample_array[j].average_grade, &sample_array[j].study_hours, &sample_array[j].pass_or_fail);
    }

    // Reading the students to be evaluated
    for (int i = 0; i < n_students_to_be_evaluated; i++) {
        scanf("%f %f", &evaluated_array[i].average_grade, &evaluated_array[i].study_hours);
    }

    // Processing
    for (int i = 0; i < n_students_to_be_evaluated; i++) {
        pass_count = 0;
        fail_count = 0;

        // Calculating distances and sorting using Heap Sort
        for (int j = 0; j < n_samples; j++) {
            sample_array[j].distance = sqrt(((evaluated_array[i].study_hours - sample_array[j].study_hours)*(evaluated_array[i].study_hours - sample_array[j].study_hours)) +
                                              ((evaluated_array[i].average_grade - sample_array[j].average_grade)*(evaluated_array[i].average_grade - sample_array[j].average_grade)));
        }

        heapSort(sample_array, n_samples);

        // Counting the number of passed and failed among the k nearest ones
        for (int g = 0; g < k; g++) {
            if (sample_array[g].pass_or_fail == 1)
                pass_count++;
            else
                fail_count++;
        }

        // Checking if the student passed or failed
        if (pass_count > fail_count) {
            printf("Student %d: (%.2f, %.2f) = Passed\n", i, evaluated_array[i].average_grade, evaluated_array[i].study_hours);
        } else {
            printf("Student %d: (%.2f, %.2f) = Failed\n", i, evaluated_array[i].average_grade, evaluated_array[i].study_hours);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}


I tried to allocate dynamically and use mergesort. Also tried to increase the size of the array in static form
